# Table-per-type inheritance with EF 4.1 Fluent Code First

Tags: entity-framework, table-per-type

I have the following tables

```
Item
-------------------
ItemId (PK)
Name

Properties
-------------------
PropertyId (PK)
Name

ItemProperties
-------------------
ItemId (FK) (CPK)
PropertyId (FK) (CPK)
Value
```

and the following classes

```
class Item{
     ItemId;
     Name;
     Properties (Collection of type ItemProperty);
}

class Property{
     PropertyId;
     Name;
}

class ItemProperty : Property{
     Value;
}
```

Using EF Fluent API how do I map the above.

Comment: Your model does not fit in for `TPT` because `ItemProperties` PK is different from `Properties` PK.

Answer (score 1):

To make @Eranga's comment more clear. Your database is not inheritance at all it is many-to-many relationship with additional data in junction table! It is mapped this way:

```
public class Item 
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemProperty> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemProperty
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

And mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ItemProperty>().HasKey(ip => new { ip.ItemId, ip.PropertyId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasMany(i => i.Properties)
                .WithRequired(ip => ip.Item)
                .HasForeignKey(ip => ip.ItemId); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Items)
                .WithRequired(ip => ip.Property)
                .HasForeignKey(ip => ip.PropertyId); 
}
```